# kubectl - error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, kubernetes-apiserver

We are getting an error when querying container logs `kubectl logs <pod>`.

This is probably related to expired certs on the worker node itself.

When deleting a pod, it is correctly rescheduled on the problematic node.

How does scheduling work, while `kubectl logs` fails? As far as I understand both requests go through the `api-server`.

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version and where do you run it?

Comment: Kubernetes version is `v1.17.1`.

Platform is an OpenShift Kubernetes distribution, if this behaviour is not native to a vanilla Kubernetes distribution I can update the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Is there any particular reason why are you using `kubectl` nstead of `oc`? The `oc` binary offers a built-in login command which allows authentication. See [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/cli_reference/differences_oc_kubectl.html).

Comment: `oc` binary is used to login

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting familiar with the whole scheduling process by going through the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/):

> kube-scheduler is the default scheduler for Kubernetes and runs as
> part of the control plane. kube-scheduler is designed so that, if you
> want and need to, you can write your own scheduling component and use
> that instead.

The Kubernetes scheduler is a control plane process which assigns Pods to Nodes. The scheduler determines which Nodes are valid placements for each Pod in the scheduling queue according to constraints and available resources.

Both [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-apiserver) and [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-scheduler) are the [control plane components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#control-plane-components):

> The control plane's components make global decisions about the cluster
> (for example, scheduling), as well as detecting and responding to
> cluster events (for example, starting up a new pod when a deployment's
> replicas field is unsatisfied).

I am no expert in Openshift but to better understand the authentication/authorization and certificates aspects of this platform I would read through [these docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/authentication/understanding-authentication.html).